# UBI file system Error -16

Tags: linux, filesystems, ubifs

During bootup, the storage partition is getting loaded. However I see this error message. What is this error 16 represents?

```
UBI error: ubi_open_volume: cannot open device 0, volume 0, error -16
```

I could also see errors like

```
initvars_srom_pci, SROM CRC Error
UBI error: ubi_wl_init: wl_init done 58 avail pebs, 688 reserved, free_count 146
```

Can someone point-out what are these errors are about? If the UBIFS file system is mounted with these errors, what is the effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem with Debian Stretch with kernel 4.13 on an armel platform. The error message comes from file

```
./drivers/mtd/ubi/kapi.c
```

The location of the error is

```
case UBI_READWRITE:
        if (vol->exclusive || vol->writers > 0) goto out_unlock;
```

I guess it's more or less harmless and comes from trying to mount the device twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
  UBI error: ubi_open_volume: cannot open device 0, volume 0, error -16
```

During bootup, it will read all erase blocks and CRC checksum is verified. Looks like the above error is because of CRC check failure of the bad erase blocks.